# django template <select> box is not selecting value

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Django template my select box is not selecting value i have the following code.

template_name.html

```
<select name="class_id" >
{% for object in classes %}
    <option value="{{ object.id }}"
        {% if object.id == class_id %} selected="selected" {% endif %}>
        {{ object.name }}
    </option>
{% endfor %}
</select>
```

view.py

```
class_id = request.POST.get('class_id', 0)
context_data = {'class_id':class_id}
return render(request, "template_name.html",context_data)
```

This behaviour is strange because we i run this code in template

```
{% for object in classes %}
    {{ object.id }} = {{ class_id }} <br>
{% endfor %}
```

then i get the following output

1 = 3

2 = 3

3 = 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thats because the one you are getting from post is string by default but object.id is int

in view

```
class_id = request.POST.get('class_id', 0)
context_data = {'class_id':int(class_id)}
```